# How to see log to find a boot problem

Tags: boot, log

I want to find the cause of a boot problem I have tried 
ls -ltr /var/log from antony@antony which gives me login incorrect
can someone tell me what command to use to see what has upset the boot thanks

NB when trying some commands from antony@antony then password  I get login incorrect.
Is that right?

Comment: This looks like a login problem rather than boot problem…

Answer (score 113):

For `systemd` based versions of Ubuntu (15.04 onwards) you'll need to use the `journalctl` command to view the current boot log messages (as mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/765320/233795), and here for [more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts) info on how to enable them for previous boots):

```
journalctl -b
```

Comment: How can I save it to a file.

Comment: @Lokesh journalctl -b > logsfielname.txt

Answer (score 61):

You can use two log files to view the boot problem.

```
/var/log/boot.log  ---  System boot log

/var/log/dmesg     ---  print or control the kernel ring buffer
```

Comment: Hi I keep getting login incorrect or permission denied????  Thanks

Comment: can you proivde the log file.

Comment: @Antony use `sudo` e.g. `sudo more /var/log/boot.log`

Answer (score 24):

To view kernel messages...

```
dmesg
```

or to page through the messages...

```
dmesg | less
```

> The program helps users to print out their kernel messages.  Instead of
>   copying the messages by hand, the user only needs to enter at the console:
>   `$ dmesg > kernel.messages`
>   and mail the `kernel.messages` file to whoever can debug their problem.

Comment: Thanks but from antony@antony I get Login incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

I am using `sudo dmesg -T --color=always --level=err,warn  | more` to see kernel errors and warnings

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add to previous useful answers, boot log is populated with many rows. Only a few of then will help you fixing the issue. Filter the reading of the most appropriate log  file with `grep` may speed up your research.
In my case, issue keyword was "hid", so gave me the very rows I was interested in:

```
a@acero:~$
journalctl -b  | grep hid
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-SYNA7DB5:01: failed to reset device: -61
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-SYNA7DB5:01: failed to reset device: -61
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-SYNA7DB5:01: failed to reset device: -61
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-SYNA7DB5:01: failed to reset device: -61
Jul 01 07:40:50 acero kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-SYNA7DB5:01: can't add hid device: -61
Jul 01 07:41:05 acero kernel: hid-generic 0003:10C4:8108.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:03:00.3-2/input0
```