# At first boot up only background is shown, how do I continue?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have a **lenovo g505s** laptop and after successfully install of Ubuntu.
When I booted it up for the first time it shows a background image and then nothing happens.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop into tty1-6. The keyboard map is usually `Ctrl+Alt+F[#]`.

Example:

```
Ctrl+Alt+F1 - tty1
Ctrl+Alt+F2 - tty2
...
```

Once you're at the command line you can try to figure out why the boot into the GUI failed.

Try [checking the logs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91286/how-to-see-log-to-find-a-boot-problem).