# Intel driver not installed

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows. In the past, it always worked fine. Now, when booting up Ubuntu as usual from the GRUB menu, the screen flickers between a line saying

`/dev/sda5/ clean, .../... files, .../... blocks`

and a loading screen of Ubuntu. I have waited ten minutes at occasions, but it still didn't load.

If I boot up Ubuntu but add `nomodeset` after the `quiet splash`, it just shows the line `/dev/sda5 clean ...` and nothing happens.

I tried starting from recovery mode, and then resumed. This gives 

`[FAILED] Failed to start Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up`

If I press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, I can log in, and proceed as usual in a non-graphic environment.

This made me suspect there was something wrong with the driver. Indeed, the output from `lshw -c video` is rather odd: the configuration line says

`configuration: latency=0`

as if there's no driver. Furthermore, `lspci -kvnn`, in the VGA compatible controller has no line `Kernel driver in use:`. It does have a line `Kernel modules: i915`.

Things I've tried:

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072420

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates # x-updates has been replaced by updates
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

with the following text being put in the file:

`Section "Device" 
Identifier "Card0" 
Driver "intel" 
Option "AccelMethod" "sna" 
EndSection`

However, this didn't work: when rebooting normally, it would exhibit the same problems, and strangely, the xorg.conf file disappears.

So my question is: how can I get the Intel driver installed correctly?

Comment: `Kernel modules: i915` means the driver is installed, as expected with Intel graphics drivers. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @MichaelBay Do you know where this "somewhere else" might be?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. But you should check the logs (that I'm not sure which ones either and I'm not at my usual PC to check it out).

Comment: @MichaelBay What kind of logs? I really don't know where to look

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/765320/692175