# Where is the output from startup scripts stored in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: boot, startup, 19.10, log

By removing the parameters `quiet` and `splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line at the `/etc/default/grub` file, I am able to display the messages displayed by system startup scripts (services) to the screen during Ubuntu boot.

However, these messages are scrolling very fast and it is practically impossible to catch any `FAILED` messages. The file `/var/log/boot.log` used to hold these messages. For example:

```
# grep -a FAILED /var/log/boot.log
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
...
```

However, this file is no longer updated (since April 2019) on my system, which suggests that starting with Ubuntu 19.04 it is deprecated. Where can I find that content on Ubuntu 19.10? Is there a way to capture the data displayed by init scripts on the console during boot to a file?

### Note

The same functionality (i.e., the exact console text output) is *not* provided by `journalctl`. For example:

```
# journalctl -b 0 | grep Raise
Jan 13 12:01:25 ... systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jan 13 12:01:25 ... systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been around since Ubuntu 16.04:

- [No more boot logging since 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763638/no-more-boot-logging-since-16-04#comment1910684_771406)

Answers there also recommend `journalctl` but buried in comments:

> I confirm that when configuring `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` in
>   `/etc/default/grub` than `boot.log` is not written. When using
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` than boot.log is again
>   written. I use Ubuntu 19.04. – adrhc Jun 9 '19 at 11:21

When I first started using **16.04** I recall `/var/log/boot.log` was empty but I didn't care enough to investigate. I looked after reading this question and now it is populated. There was a bug that has since been fixed:

- [#791907 bootlogd: /var/log/boot is empty with systemd](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=791907)

There may have been a bug regression in **19.10** or the `sysvinit` package is not installed. On my **16.04** installation I have this:

```
$ apt list | grep sysv | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

    sysv-rc/xenial,xenial,now 2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2 all [installed]
    sysvinit-utils/xenial,now 2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
```

To those that do not know, the advantage of `/var/log/boot.log` over `journalctl -b` is the color formatting that mirrors the console boot messages:

[image: boot.log.png]

Comment: This does not work for me in Ubuntu 18.04 unfortunately. (Yes, I ran `sudo update-grub`.) Anyway, is there any bug report regarding this?

Comment: Same here as @Melebius : I tested both `"quiet splash"` and `"nosplash"` (followed by `update-grub`) on 19.10, but no `boot.log`.

Comment: @Melebius I found the bug report from 16.04 and added a link.

Comment: Thank you for the update but I still haven’t found advice on how to make `boot.log` working on my machine (18.04) or newer (OP’s 19.10) in your answer. It currently looks just like a very extensive comment… The [`bootlogd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bootlogd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package last appeared in 16.04.

Comment: @Melebius Do you have the `sysvinit` packages installed as shown in my answer update?

Comment: I have `sysvinit-utils` installed but [`sysv-rc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sysv-rc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) last appeared in 16.04, too.

Comment: I think that is for rc.local service to run programs on startup with Sudo permissions and may not be required in your case.

Comment: I am terribly sorry WinEunuuchs2Unix . The closest answer to my question was yours. And it did deserve the bounty. However, I mistakenly click the @starkus 's answer for awarding the bounty and the system does not allow me to undo it! :(

Comment: A mod can probably fix that.

Comment: I informed mods. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries. I upvoted both your Q&A to help offset your bounty costs :)

Answer (score 2):

After doing some tests, I finally got the following:

1. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445744/how-to-unmask-bootlogd-service).
2. `Bootlogd` is no longer supported. `Plymouth` service takes over. The file `/etc/default/bootlogd` is irrelevant.
3. For `plymouth.service` to log messages to `/var/log/boot.log` file, the file `/etc/default/grub` should contain the following line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Otherwise plymouth service will not log anything to `boot.log`!

So, the answer of @WinEunuuchs2Unix  is more or less the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

One may view messages from *this* boot with

```
sudo journalctl -b 0
```

Read `man journalctl` and see my AskUbuntu profile for `journalctl` hints.

Comment: Yes, that is something I looked into. However, the format is not the same as the contents of `boot.log` which is exactly the same as the text displayed on the console during boot.