# How to log messages from init.d scripts

Tags: logging, init.d

I have this script in /etc/init.d, but I don't see any of its log messages in /var/log. They are of the form:

```
echo "ACM: here I am!" >&2
```

Since they are all prefixed w/"ACM", grep'ing "ACM" should make it easy to figure out where they are, but they don't seem to be anywhere.

I have a symlink in /etc/rc0.d/ given as

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 19 11:13 K01b2umount -> ../init.d/umountb2

And in /etc/init.d/ is a script that has the same permissions as all its peers. So I don't see why it wouldn't be executed. There's no way to execute that script without generating log messages, so where are they?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: Aren't SystemV scripts converted to systemd service units nowadays (by `systemd-sysv-generator`)? Have you checked the systemd journal (ex. `journalctl | grep umount`)

Comment: May be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202455/where-is-the-output-from-startup-scripts-stored-in-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: Read `man logger`.

Comment: @steeldriver I tried that, but it never showed any of those log messages in my script.

Comment: @waltinator After I did, I changed some of the log messages to `logger "ACM: here I am"` I still got no joy, whether I looked into `journalctl` or grep'd /var/log for it.