# How can I read and capture error messages that appear on the screen before login?

Tags: 16.04, boot, logging

I am having errors pop up quickly (can't read them) before my login window appears. I can't find them in syslog. Is there some way I can figure out what these errors are?

Comment: Will this work? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203743/saving-linux-boot-messages-in-a-file

Comment: use `dmesg` or go `dmesg > dmesg.log` & the log will be in your home folder to read thru.

Answer (score 5):

Executing `journalctl -b` "should do the trick" ... this will show the journal entries that have been collected since the most recent reboot. `journalctl -b -1` shows the entries from the boot event before. Reference (and information) : [How To Use Journalctl to View and Manipulate Systemd Logs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs)

To see additional options you have with `journalctl`, such like `journalctl -b --list-boots`,
you can check them out by executing the commands `journalctl --help` or `man journalctl`.

Comment: +1 `journalctl` is powerful tool. If you have 16.04 you can't see previous boots until you configure it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1008210/307523