# where can I find the logs for shutdown by a root user?

Tags: shutdown, log

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

The issue I am facing is that, when I type in the command "shutdown -h now" as a root user, it is not logged anywhere in syslog, auth.log or kern.log.

But when a user with sudo permission does the same, it is logged in auth.log.

So, where can I find the logs for the first case?.

Comment: Command history is viewable with `history` (which includes date & time if setup to record it). I'd also suggest upgrading your system (it should be 14.04.6  (14.04.4 was released 18-Feb-2016 so your system looks long behind in upgrades and thus security fixes)

Comment: "So, where can I find the logs for the first case?"  You are missing crucial infomation: are you using systemd?  And this should answer your question though it is not the same the solution is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts/774309#774309