# Ubuntu restarts randomly / how to read what caused system restarts

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, 64-bit, 19.04

I am a new user to Ubuntu, I decided to install fresh system on my new laptop (w/out OS inside). However after all I have a problem that i can not deal with. My Ubuntu restarts randomly, I was trying to find a solution but unfortunately none of them helped.

My supposition is directing me to the problem with the graphics card or hardware issue. One of the dependencies I have noticed is that the system reboots much more often when I am working with a web browser (YouTube), jumping between windows etc. During gaming tests on the steam platform, the problem practically did not occur except for the suspiciously high temperature of the laptop case.

What I tried:

1. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -> upgraded to 19.04
2. Tested all possible nvidia drivers and distro free
3. Change Grub configuration (`acpi=force` / `nouveau.modeset=0`)
4. Update BIOS version (I haven't changed much in BIOS config., tried to disable Legacy)

And here we come to the conclusion of my post. Unfortunately, my knowledge is basic and I can't read log informations to understand what causes reboots and what should I do next. Below I drop some logs and settings.

- [Last reboot](https://pastebin.com/ntVX28Cu)
- [`dmesg`](https://pastebin.com/3hPEN6cB)
- [boot log](https://pastebin.com/6MLyXiD7)
- [`tail /var/log/syslog`](https://pastebin.com/MhgyN9qL)
- [`lscpi`](https://pastebin.com/rV4XW0ER)
- [`nvidia-smi`](https://pastebin.com/D9BcUGpT)

Comment: Is there a log of when system crashed? eg `journalctl -b-1 -xe`. Note multiple boot logging needs to be enabled: [How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04+ restarts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts/1008210#1008210). If no multi-boot logging then `gedit /var/log/syslog` and page backwards to crash/reboot.

Comment: last reboot is from 12.32:
https://pastebin.com/RpnxQbaB

Comment: So you're saying it crashed while starting fingerprint authentication? That sounds like a beginning of boot feature...