# How to diagnose system boot issues

Tags: boot, kernel

I have my main laptop which boots 19.04 fine with 5.0.3-45 kernel, but boots repeatedly to an black screen on 5.0.3-46 and 5.0.3-51 kernels.

The black screen is entirely non-responsive - no cursor - no response to any inputs. The only way to recover is to hit the power button, and reboot to the grub menu.

The one thing that has always alluded me is how to diagnose boot issues like this - so if anyone has any tips it would be greatly appreciated.

It would also be useful to understand how to ensure that 5.0.3-45 doesn't get removed by an upgrade, at least until after I am able to boot into one of the other kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy :) My guess is you can't <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to `systemd-analize blame` or `journalctl` ?
For boot logs, you'll find everything you need in [that post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts).

---

**TL;DR**

According to that post, there are no logs of previous boots because it would be storage disk waste.
You need to enable it

```
sudo -i
mkdir -p /var/log/journal
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
systemctl restart systemd-journald
exit
```

Then everything will log.

You can list the existing logs with
`journalctl --list-boots` then read the logs with `journalctl -b-#` (substitute the `#` with the appropriate number : 1 for last boot, 2 for the one before, 3 for the one before again, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I have the log file - ... I now need to work out what it means ...

Comment: Sadly I can't see anything in the relevant logs that suggests what this issue might be - in fact the errors that get reported on 5.0.3-51 are the same as the ones reported on 5.0.3-46 (in fact 3-46 boot has more errors as it runs to completion.
There is nothing in the 3-51 boot log that gives any clue as to why the boot simply stops.