# Ubuntu machine goes into sleep after giving reboot command

Tags: boot, suspend, power-management, 20.04, reboot

I am running the latest Ubuntu LTS version: 20.04 on my Dell 7050 Micro.

When I enter the command: `reboot` and press enter, it does the normal reboot sequence, but **most of the time** the machine doesn't come back online, unless I press the power button of the Dell again.

The power button light is fading on/off and I have no idea why this is happening. The only difference is that I see the following line on the screen before it goes into sleep mode or something:

> "A suspend job running for...".

What is happening here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I had a similar problem installing on a 7010 thin client... when i got ubuntu to install, I could not reboot or shutdown... The problem had to do something with the UEFI they used. It didn't "sleep" more hung, but I had to poweroff hard with the button. The "fix" I settled for was installing in legacy mode, which did not work on that device either.... so I put the drive in an older machine in legacy mode and then transferred the drive back... It's worked fine since. This is not the answer to "What is happening here" but it may provide some ideas.

Comment: what happens if you `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Here is a reverse of this problem. Laptop reboots instead of resuming from suspend: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291546/laptop-reboots-instead-of-resuming-from-systemd-suspend-when-on-battery-power-s

Comment: This might help https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1536764. It's a bug in Redhat, it could exit in Ubuntu too though.

Comment: I would try to [look at previous boot logs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008210/349837), probably with `journalctl -p err -k`.

Comment: It says: `Ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip`