# PC restarts after playing a vlc video for some time --troubleshooting

Tags: crash, reboot, troubleshooting

I've bought a new pc setup a couple of days ago and installed Ubuntu on the machine. When I play a certain video, it restarts after a while on VLC. Playing videos on YouTube doesn't cause this problem and playing other videos on VLC doesn't cause it either.

How can I troubleshoot this problem and see why the pc crashes and restarts ?

Additional info:

`/proc/sys/kernel/panic;` is set to `0`

`journalctl -x -p err` results are:

```
 09 08:55:18 pc-A520M-S2H kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PLTF.C00C (20210331>
 09 08:55:18 pc-A520M-S2H kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PLTF.C00D (20210331>
 09 08:55:18 pc-A520M-S2H kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PLTF.C00E (20210331>
 09 08:55:18 pc-A520M-S2H kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PLTF.C00F (20210331>
 09 08:55:23 pc-A520M-S2H wpa_supplicant[831]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
 09 08:55:23 pc-A520M-S2H wpa_supplicant[831]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
 09 08:55:23 pc-A520M-S2H wpa_supplicant[831]: ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
 09 08:55:24 pc-A520M-S2H NetworkManager[809]: <error> [1654757724.5493] wifi-wext: (wlxd03745e54257): error setting powersave 1
 09 08:55:25 pc-A520M-S2H wpa_supplicant[831]: Failed to add supported operating classes IE
 09 08:55:26 pc-A520M-S2H wpa_supplicant[831]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
 09 08:55:27 pc-A520M-S2H gdm-password][1416]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 09 08:55:48 pc-A520M-S2H pulseaudio[1451]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service '>
-- Reboot --
```

Problem persists with live boot.

Processor: Ryzen 5 5600g, Ram: 16GB.
Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS focal.

It could be that the power supply is undervolting, but I've set the CPU frequency to 80% and still restarts. Is there a way to troubleshoot the PSU?

Comment: Check logs `journalctl -xe -b -k`. Maybe a temperature issue? Did you try doing the same on a live boot?

Comment: Done thanks for clarifying the issue

Comment: [Set logs to persist multiple boots](https://askubuntu.com/a/1008210/349837) and then check exactly when the PC crash, start using `sudo journalctl -x` (probably `-p err` will return less noise)

Comment: I've updated with a complete log of what happens in between the reboots.. but it seems pretty normal to me. does it mean it's a hardware problem ? if that's the case is there steps to identify where the issue lies ?

Comment: This strikes me as a potential vulnerability exploit. Can you create a virtual machine with Gnome Boxes and try running the video on there? If it crashes the VM when you do this, I'd save the video file on a flash drive, reinstall Ubuntu entirely to clean up any potential malware, and then proceed with further debugging steps to see if it affects the latest version of VLC in a VM.

Comment: Those errors don't seem related. Already check with lower `-p`? Computer is up-to-date? That certain video with a live boot on other PC doesn't crash? Add the output of relevant lines of `mediainfo certainvideo`

Comment: I have another laptob with ubuntu 22 loaded on it, it doesn't crash the laptob. I don't think it's not related to vlc program itself as the pc does the same crash when I'm browsing pinterest.com with multiple videos on the page. but I'm playing some courses for a while now and my pc is not crashing. and youtube is working just fine.

Comment: I have tried lowering CPU power to 50%,also running fans at maximum speed, I even tried re installing ubuntu.. the problem is the same