# Why are the previous boot.log files missing?

Tags: boot, 20.04, log

Laptop is an Acer Aspire V3-772 with 8GB and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Gnome 42.9 & Wayland on UEFI

My friends laptop suffers from shutdown problems and I wanted to take a look at the previous boot.log to see what caused the shutdown, but there is only 1 boot.log file showing when I ask for the logs with `ls /var/log` and that is the current boot.log.

```
auth.log  boot.log  btmp  cups  dmesg  gdm3  gpu-manager.log  journal  kern.log  lastlog  private  syslog  ubuntu-advantage.log  unattended-upgrades  wtmp
```

And when taking a look at journals:

```
$ /var/log/journal
$ ls
9be0c0a693aa409aa7b4e30f37396627
```

this also results in just one (the current) journal.

I do not know if the situation has ever be different, i.e. if older log files were retained once, maybe the system always behaved in this manner.

I learned that the behavior of logs depends on logrotate.conf, so here I give its content.

The result of `sudo nano /etc/logrotate.conf` is pretty standard I guess:

```
# global options do not affect preceding include directives

# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
#dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may also be configured here.
```

I am not sure if the following errors which are marked as important in the current log might be related, but here they are:

> ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)

> ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)

> Can't chdir to /var/spool/anacron: No such file or directory

> Timed out waiting for device /sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmbus!hv_kvp.

> Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

I looked everywhere for information on missing log files, but to no avail.
How this could have happened, why are the older log files, older than the current, missing?

EDIT:

I have read that in cases that only the current log can be viewed, there is no directory journal in `/etc/var/` and should be created, OR that in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` the option `storage = persistent` should be set which would cause the directory `journal` to be created, thus solving the problem.

But because in my system the `journal` directory already exists and setting `storage = persistent` did not make any difference, I wonder if it is safe to try to delete the `journal` directory and let it be created through the mechanism that should result from having `storage = persistent` been set.

Maybe when created in that automatic way this will result in a system with persistent logs?

Comment: take a look https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts/1008210#1008210  here please.

Comment: Logs are now managed by `journalctl`. `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -ex`, for example, shows the log messages leading up to the previous shotdown,  with eXtended error messages. Read `man journalctl `, do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`.

Comment: @waltinator: sudo journalctl --list-boots also gives just one

Comment: @all: I edited the question to add a sub-question concerning the possibility of deleting the journal-directory in order to have that being re-created, please comment.

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs it explains how to enable persistent `journalctl` data. BTW, simply deleting an in-use directory is an obdolete idea, don't do it. Either reboot (`sudo shutdown -r now`) or restart the `journalctl` servicr.

Comment: @waltinator: What I wrote under the EDIT in my question is exactly what is told in your link, so this does not work.