# What is the function of bootstrap.log?

Tags: 20.04, log, debootstrap

I encountered the existence of a file named `bootstrap.log` in the `/var/log` directory when trying to solve a [log related problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486121/why-are-the-previous-boot-log-files-missing) and when looking at its content I saw that the timestamps are over a year old.

It seems to be consisting of a lot FTP-links, dpkg-warnings like "ignoring pre-dependency problem!" and information concerning unpacking .deb-packages, which seems to be pointing to installation related data.

To see if a relation existed with the installation date I did:

```
$ ls -lt /var/log/installer
total 752
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 387038 dec 17  2022 initial-status.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 277005 dec 17  2022 syslog
-rw------- 1 root root   1509 dec 17  2022 casper.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     64 dec 17  2022 media-info
-rw------- 1 root root  91778 dec 17  2022 debug
```

From which I conclude that the installation took place at dec 17, 2022.

The timestamped entries in bootstrap.log all start with 2022-08-09, so this would be before the installation.

I searched for information on bootstrap.log, but could not find enlightening information on the subject.

This made me wonder what exactly the of use `bootstrap.log` is, why it has been created and if its content will change at all after its original creation date.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 7):

That log file was created by the utility(*program*) used to prepare (*install into a directory on some machine*) your Ubuntu system before it was made into an ISO image to be downloaded and installed on user machines like yours.

It's there as a verification (*trace origin*) mechanism.

It's not going to change in your already installed Operating System's lifetime.

The remote links i.e. FTP, HTTP ... etc. or local ones and files are the addresses/links to resources on which the original resources(*Ubuntu or Debian systems*) were kept.

This process is in layman's terms, a process during which an original system gets selectively installed into a separate directory while selecting(*or even creating/adding*) or excluding certain parts(*packages, hierarchy, files and links*) of that system to create a certain target "flavor" for a certain architecture based on a pre-configured set of instructions.

Two famous tools used for that process are [`debootstrap`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/debootstrap.8.html) and [`cdebootstrap`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/cdebootstrap.1.html) ... `/var/log/bootstrap.log` is likely created by the latter one.

Answer (score 4):

See the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/cdebootstrap.1.html):

> cdebootstrap  builds  a  basic  Debian system of CODENAME (e.g. jessie, stretch, sid) from
> ORIGIN (e.g Debian, Ubuntu) into TARGET using the source specified in MIRROR.  It supports
> http://, ftp://, file:// and ssh:// URL and defaults to http://ftp.debian.org/debian.  The
> ssh:// scheme uses cat on the remote host to access the files.  You have to setup a master
> connection  and  configure  ssh  to  use  it  or  use  a  key  for authentication. No user
> interaction is possible.  The complete log is saved as /var/log/bootstrap.log in  the  new
> system.
>
> ...
>
> FLAVOURS
>
> Flavours available with default configuration:
>
> `build`  Installs  essential,  apt  and  build-essential.   Suitable for sbuild and pbuilder
> usage.  All rc.d operations are disabled by  a  policy-rc.d  script  (cdebootstrap-
> helper-rc.d package).
>
> `minimal` Installs  essential  and  apt.   All  rc.d operations are disabled by a policy-rc.d
> script (cdebootstrap-helper-rc.d package).
>
> `standard`   Installs required and important priority packages.  This is the default flavour.

Comment: :-) I started by editing your answer to make it easier to understand for broader audience "*man pages, although a great reference, can be hard to get the general point from ... especially when the tool is rarely or never used by most users*" ... And then the edit became too complicated to be just an edit ,,, So, posted it as an answer instead :-) ... **+1**