# Kubuntu randomly freezes (only) on startup

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, startup, freeze

I have double boot on my Lenovo B71-80 with Kubuntu 17.04 and Linux Mint 18.2. Both systems randomly (and pretty similarly) freeze on startup, while showing (kubuntu or LM) splash screen. When I switch off splash screen in grub, I see that on different occasions the system freezes at different stages: one time trying to mount swap partition, another time doing something else. After I switch off the notebook with the power button (it doesn't answer to REISUB) and press the button again, the system usually starts and works flawlessly. There are no freezes after the system has already started successfully.

dmesg -T gives the following messages in bold about the unsuccessful startup:

```
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: RSDP 0x0000000077FFD014 000024 (v02 LENOVO)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: XSDT 0x0000000077FCB188 0000FC (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001      01000013)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: FACP 0x0000000077FEB000 00010C (v05 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: DSDT 0x0000000077FD0000 016C8F (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: FACS 0x0000000077F6B000 000040
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: TCPA 0x0000000077FFC000 000032 (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: UEFI 0x0000000077FFB000 000236 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: UEFI 0x0000000077FFA000 000042 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FF9000 0004B7 (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FF8000 00004B (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: TPM2 0x0000000077FF7000 000034 (v03 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: MSDM 0x0000000077FF6000 000055 (v03 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FF2000 0030A9 (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: DBGP 0x0000000077FF1000 000034 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: DBG2 0x0000000077FF0000 000054 (v00 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: ASF! 0x0000000077FEF000 0000A5 (v32 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: ASPT 0x0000000077FEE000 000034 (v07 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: BOOT 0x0000000077FED000 000028 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: DBGP 0x0000000077FEC000 000034 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: HPET 0x0000000077FEA000 000038 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: LPIT 0x0000000077FE9000 000094 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: APIC 0x0000000077FE8000 0000BC (v03 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: MCFG 0x0000000077FE7000 00003C (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FCF000 0002D4 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FCC000 002BAE (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FCA000 000B39 (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FC9000 000E58 (v02 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000077FC7000 001B2B (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: DMAR 0x0000000077FC6000 0000A8 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: FPDT 0x0000000077FC5000 000044 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: BGRT 0x0000000077FC4000 000038 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: 9 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] PCCT header not found.
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] pmd_set_huge: Cannot satisfy [mem 0xe0000000-0xe0200000] with a huge-page mapping due to MTRR override.
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Executed 17 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF93573C44A800 00061E (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20121220)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: \_PR_.CPU0: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF93573C462800 00037F (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20121220)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF93573C44E000 0005AA (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20121220)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF93573C528800 000119 (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20121220)
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
[Вт сен 12 17:24:20 2017] ACPI: Enabled 5 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[Вт сен 12 17:24:21 2017] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[Вт сен 12 17:24:21 2017] ATPX version 1, functions 0x00000033
[Вт сен 12 17:24:21 2017] ATPX Hybrid Graphics
[Вт сен 12 17:24:21 2017] CRAT table not found
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[Вт сен 12 17:24:31 2017] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

What can possibly be the reason? Is there any way to localize and fix this problem?

Comment: You can inspect `/var/log/syslog`, `dmesg -T` or  `/var/log/boot.log` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/91286/how-to-see-log-to-find-a-boot-problem). I suggest you to take note exact time when it freezes and see what messages it told about it.

Comment: Thanks! Here are the fields shown in bold by dmesg about the unsuccessful boot (they are absent from the successful one):

[Вт сен 12 16:22:51 2017] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[Вт сен 12 16:22:51 2017] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[Вт сен 12 16:22:52 2017] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored

Comment: Three more messages in bold:
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[Вт сен 12 17:24:30 2017] uvcvideo 1-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!

Comment: Eugene, it's better you post these messages into your question. It makes things easier to understand. Like I did right now