# 20.04 "Error found when loading /home/user/.profile Failed to write reboot parameter file" after boot

Tags: boot, permissions, .profile

Every time I boot into Ubuntu I get this error message

```
Error found when loading /home/user/.profile  
Failed to write reboot parameter file: permission denied
```

Everything seems to work normally afterwards.
I use GRUB to boot into Windows or Ubuntu on different SSDs.

Any help is appreciated.

This is what my `/home/user/.profile` looks like:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

#pactl set-default-source alsa_input.usb-R__DE_Microphones_R__DE_NT-USB_Mini_0C664231-00.mono-fallback
#pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a faulty alias defined in `.bashrc`. Removing that solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Below I give tentative solutions.
In the meantime, please post the following info:

1. It seems an error like that should appear not after booting, but after logging into you account, is that correct?
2. Is `user` a sudoer?

**Tentative solutions**:

1. If `user` is not a sudoer, try making it so and check if the problem persists.
2. Try examining boot log files to see if you can identify the problem and/or the file that is causing the reported error, see [How to see log to find a boot problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91286/how-to-see-log-to-find-a-boot-problem). Then try changing the permissions on that file, or adding `user` to a group that can write to that file.

Please post feedback in the question on what you get.
It is most convenient to post results in markdown formatted text, not as screen captures.

**Related**:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/176165/where-linux-places-the-messages-of-boot

Comment: You're right, the message occurred after loggin in the user. user is a memer of the sudo group. It turned out that removing a faulty alias in .bashrc solved the problem. Thank you for your Help!

Comment: @DanielH - Glad that you solved it... I expected that following the breadcrumbs you could manage.