# How to enable boot.log in Ubuntu (Jammy)?

Tags: 22.04

How to enable the boot.log in the Ubuntu (Jammy)? Currently, /var/log/boot.log is the empty file. And during the boot I see some yellow and red messages from services. Is there a file where all boot messages are being saved?

Comment: Try /var/log/syslog

Comment: The comment by user535733 is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see log to find a boot problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91286/how-to-see-log-to-find-a-boot-problem)

Comment: boot.log is the empty file in my system. Syslog contains all necessary information.